# Create a ListView with LoadMoreItemsAsync on end of scroll

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `ListView` in my Windows Phone 8.1 application and I can have something like 1000 or more results, so I need to implement a Load More feature each time the scroll hits bottom, or some other logic and natural way of triggering the adding of more items to the List.
I found that the `ListView` has support for an `ISupportIncrementalLoading`, and found this implementation: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/implementing-the-isupportincrementalloading-interface-in-a-window-store-app/
This was the better solution I found, since it does not specify a type, i.e., it's generic.

My problem with this solution is that when the ListView is Loaded, the `LoadMoreItemsAsync` runs all the times needed until it got all the results, meaning that the Load More is not triggered by the user. I'm not sure what make the `LoadMoreItemsAsync` trigger, but something is not right, because it assumes that happens when I open the page and loads all items on the spot, without me doing anything, or any scrolling. Here's the implementation:
`IncrementalLoadingCollection.cs`

```
public interface IIncrementalSource<T> {
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetPagedItems(int pageIndex, int pageSize);
    void SetType(int type);
}

public class IncrementalLoadingCollection<T, I> : ObservableCollection<I>, ISupportIncrementalLoading where T : IIncrementalSource<I>, new() {
    private T source;
    private int itemsPerPage;
    private bool hasMoreItems;
    private int currentPage;

    public IncrementalLoadingCollection(int type, int itemsPerPage = 10) {
        this.source = new T();
        this.source.SetType(type);
        this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
        this.hasMoreItems = true;
    }

    public bool HasMoreItems {
        get { return hasMoreItems; }
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count) {
        var dispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

        return Task.Run<LoadMoreItemsResult>(
            async () => {
                uint resultCount = 0;
                var result = await source.GetPagedItems(currentPage++, itemsPerPage);

                if(result == null || result.Count() == 0) {
                    hasMoreItems = false;
                }
                else {
                    resultCount = (uint)result.Count();

                    await dispatcher.RunAsync(
                        CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        () => {
                            foreach(I item in result)
                                this.Add(item);
                        });
                }

                return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = resultCount };

            }).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
    }
}
```

Here's the `PersonModelSource.cs`

```
public class DatabaseNotificationModelSource : IIncrementalSource<DatabaseNotificationModel> {
    private ObservableCollection<DatabaseNotificationModel> notifications;
    private int _type = "";

    public DatabaseNotificationModelSource() {
        //
    }

    public void SetType(int type) {
        _type = type;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<DatabaseNotificationModel>> GetPagedItems(int pageIndex, int pageSize) {
        if(notifications == null) {
            notifications = new ObservableCollection<DatabaseNotificationModel>();
            notifications = await DatabaseService.GetNotifications(_type);
        }

        return await Task.Run<IEnumerable<DatabaseNotificationModel>>(() => {
            var result = (from p in notifications select p).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
                return result;
            });
    }
}
```

I changed it a bit, because the call to my Database is Asynchronous and it was the only way I found to make sure I could wait for the query before filling the collection.

And in my `DatabaseNotificationViewModel.cs`

```
IncrementalNotificationsList = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<DatabaseNotificationModelSource, DatabaseNotificationModel>(type);
```

Everything works fine, apart from the not so normal "Load More". What's wrong in my code?

Comment: I copied your code and I can't replicate the bug. It works correctly for me.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fde7d66620ee05ffa2c1) was the code I used in a new blank app project if you wanna check it out.

Comment: Have you tried adding something like 300/400 items and check the behaviour I mentioned?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many items I have, I tried it with 1000 and it still only loads more items when I scroll down toward the end of the list. There's a couple of superfluous things in your code, but I don't think that would affect the incremental loading behavior.

Comment: What does your Xaml look like? Can you provide a full repro? If the ListView is of unbounded height then it would need to load everything immediately.

Comment: Is your `ListView` inside a `StackPanel` by any chance? You can download my code from [here](https://github.com/decademoon/IncrementalLoadingTest).

Comment: I Forked your project and added navigation for testing purposes. The problema is that almost always 3 pages are loaded, but sometimes all of them are loaded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I created a very simplified example of this issue [here](https://github.com/decademoon/BadIncrementalLoading), and raised this issue on the MSDN forums [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/dc1e1fe2-6b4e-400d-a66a-d116b47f6047/isupportincrementalloading-listview-loads-too-many-items-only-when-performing-an-async-operation-in?forum=winappswithcsharp#dc1e1fe2-6b4e-400d-a66a-d116b47f6047). Honestly, I don't know why this weird behavior is happening.

**What I observed**

- The ListView will call `LoadMoreItemsAsync` first with a count of 1. I assume this is to determine the size of a single item so that it can work out the number of items to request for the next call.
- If the ListView is behaving nicely, the second call to `LoadMoreItemsAsync` should happen immediately after the first call, but with the correct number of items (count > 1), and then no more calls to `LoadMoreItemsAsync` will occur unless you scroll down. In your example, however, it may incorrectly call `LoadMoreItemsAsync` with a count of 1 *again*.
- In the worst case, which actually occurs quite frequently in your example, is that the ListView will continue to call `LoadMoreItemsAsync` with a count of 1 over and over, in order, until `HasMoreItems` becomes false, in which case it has loaded all of the items one at a time. When this happens, there is a noticeable UI delay while the ListView loads the items. *The UI thread isn't blocked, though. The ListView is just hogging the UI thread with sequential calls to `LoadMoreItemsAsync`*.
- The ListView won't always exhaust all of the items though. Sometimes it will load 100, or 200, or 500 items. In each case, the pattern is: many calls of `LoadMoreItemsAsync(1)` followed by a single call to `LoadMoreItemsAsync(> 1)` if not all of the items have been loaded by the prior calls.
- It only seems to occur on page load.
- The issue is persistent on Windows Phone 8.1 as well as Windows 8.1.

**What causes the problem**

- The issue seems to be **very short lived awaited tasks** in the `LoadMoreItemsAsync` method before you've added the items to the list (awaiting tasks after you've added the items to the list is fine).
- The issue doesn't occur if you remove all `await`s inside `LoadMoreItemsAsync`, thus forcing it to execute synchronously. Specifically, if you remove the `dispatcher.RunAsync` wrapper and `await source.GetPagedItems` (just mock the items instead), then the ListView will behave nicely.
- Having removed all `await`s, the issue will reappear even if all you add is a seemingly harmless `await Task.Run(() => {})`. How bizarre!

**How to fix the problem**

If most of the time spent in a `LoadMoreItemsAsync` call is waiting for a HTTP request for the next page of items, as I expect most apps are, then the issue won't occur. So, we can extend the time spent in the method by awaiting a `Task.Delay(10)`, like this maybe:

```cs
await Task.WhenAll(Task.Delay(10), dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    foreach (I item in result)
        this.Add(item);
}).AsTask());
```

---

I've merely provided a (hacky) workaround for your example, but not an explanation why. **If anyone knows why this is happening, please let me know.**

Comment: Funny enough, the workaround I got to consisted exactly in the same as yours, i.e., delaying. Although not the perfect solution, it is a functional solution, and from my perspective you clearly identified the source and behaviour of the problem, so I'll mark your reply as answer.

Comment: I stumbled upon the same problem and solved it by applying your hack. Hope this is solved in the future.

Comment: How is Microsoft not on top of this after all of these years? Why is there no bug fix, or at least an explanation? This is why I am moving over to iOS and macOS development. Support on UWP is scarce, and documentation is horrible. It is hard to find any sort of documentation on many APIs and so only very season developers can figure out how to use them. They rarely update documentation for APIs that they change or add, and then - like here - you can wait years for something to finally be fixed or to at least be given an explanation for what is going on with their APIs. I can go all day.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the only thing that can cause this issue.  If your ListView is inside a ScrollViewer, it will continue loading all of the items and ALSO will not virtualize properly, negatively impacting performance.  The solution is to give your ListView a specific height.