# LoadMoreItemsAsync called variable times

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, lazy-loading

I have been trying to implement `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface for an `ObservableCollection`. My implementation works for the most part but it behaves strangely under uncertain circumstances. Here is my code to `IncrementalCollection` class.

```
public class IncrementalCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, ISupportIncrementalLoading
{
    private bool hasMoreItems;
    private int currentPage;
    private string filter;

    private Func<string, int, Task<IList<T>>> func;
    Action onLoadingStarts;
    Action onLoadingEnds;

    public IncrementalCollection(Func<string, int, Task<IList<T>>> func, Action onLoadingStarts, Action onLoadingEnds)
    {
        this.func = func;
        this.hasMoreItems = true;

        this.onLoadingStarts = onLoadingStarts;
        this.onLoadingEnds = onLoadingEnds;
    }

    public void ResetCollection(string filter)
    {
        currentPage = 0;
        this.filter = filter;
        this.Clear();
    }

    public bool HasMoreItems
    {
        get { return hasMoreItems; }
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        return DoLoadMoreItemsAsync(count).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
    }

    private async Task<LoadMoreItemsResult> DoLoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        onLoadingStarts();
        var result = await func(this.filter, ++this.currentPage);
        if (result == null || result.Count == 0)
        {
            hasMoreItems = false;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (T item in result)
                this.Add(item);
        }

        onLoadingEnds();
        return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = result == null ? 0 : (uint)result.Count };
    }
}
```

The first strange behavior occurs when page loads, `LoadMoreItemsAsync` function is sometimes called once, generally twice and sometimes more than twice. This is strange as one call is enough to add enough items to the collection. I even tried to pull more data (2-3 times) but the behavior continues. There might be problem about the place of initialization of the `IncrementalCollection` object. As it seems the longer it takes to load the page the more calls are made to `LoadMoreItemsAsync` function. I am creating the collection in `NavigationHelper_LoadState` function like this.

```
_users = new IncrementalCollection<User>((filter, page) => _dataService.GetUserList(url, filter, null, page), onLoadingStarts, onLoadingEnds);
```

Second strange behavior is about caching, although I have added

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;
```

to every page constructor and also changed `NavigationHelper` not to save `pageState` on back navigation. It feels like web requests are cached as it is very hard to return a response in that amount of time.

```
public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
        return;

    var frameState = SuspensionManager.SessionStateForFrame(this.Frame);
    var pageState = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
    if (this.SaveState != null)
    {
        this.SaveState(this, new SaveStateEventArgs(pageState));
    }
    frameState[_pageKey] = pageState;
}
```

Any help about these strange behaviors is appreciated.

Also is there any good tutorial about `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface that explains `LoadMoreItemsAsync` firing conditions. I am trying to modify a WrapPanel implementation but don't know where to start as I don't know what it looks for. This is probably about `ItemHeight` but still concrete information is better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface. Solved the multiple request problem by applying the solution here [Create a ListView with LoadMoreItemsAsync on end of scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719617/create-a-listview-with-loadmoreitemsasync-on-end-of-scroll).

I wrapped the `foreach` loop inside `Task.WhenAll` call.

```
await Task.WhenAll(Task.Delay(50), Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    foreach (T item in result)
        this.Add(item);
}).AsTask());
```

Comment: The real fix here is that you are now calling 'add' on the UI thread.